# VBA to capture output, a number, from shell command

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, vba, batch-file

The following batch command generates a number, the count of the number of files whose size is greater than a threashold, 512K in this case, although the count is off by 1.

```
forfiles /P C:\ /M *.* /S /C "CMD /C if @fsize gtr 512000 echo @PATH @FSIZE"|findstr /r /n "^" |find /c ":"
```

How does one capture the output in VBA?

I have found an [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784367/capture-output-value-from-a-shell-command-in-vba) that does the same thing but the answer seems to me is quite complicated. I wonder if there is an easier way to capture the output, like assigning an integer to the shell command?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Exec method of the Shell.

eg:

```
  Dim WSH As WshShell
  Dim sOut As String

Set WSH = New WshShell
sOut = WSH.Exec("your_cmd_string").StdOut.ReadAll
```

One problem I have found with this method is that the command window stays open while the command is executing.  It can be hidden, but would require windows API calls.

As a consequence, when running shell commands from VBA, I have been using the `Run` method with the `Hidden` argument, and redirecting the results to a temporary file.

Comment: "Dim WSH As WshShell" threw an error message "user defined type not defined". Do I need to include a library? I searched the net and found no article mentioning about including any library. I use Excel 2010.

Comment: @joehua Yes, you need to set a reference to  `Windows Script Host Object Model`, although you can use late-binding if this is for distribution.

Comment: Thanks. After adding the reference, I no longer got the error message. However, when testing on a simple "dir c:\", I got another error that says "Run-time error '-2147024894 (80070002)':Method 'Exec' of object 'IWshShell3' failed." I found an article that say 8007 is an error code for Win32 but I'm running 64 bit Windows 10. Another article says this is a "file not found" error but I'm not asking the code to load any file.

Comment: @joehua I suspect there are errors in your command line. Try reading from `StdErr` instead of `StdOut` and see what's in there.  You'll have problems accessing certain files with that command.

Comment: I got the exact same error when replacing 'StdOut' with 'StdErr'.

Comment: @joehua I cannot reproduce your error

Comment: After adding the reference, I changed the string "your_cmd_string" to "dir c:\" and got the error. I then changed the word "StdOut" to "StdErr" and got the same error. That's all I can say. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: @joehua That's what I did for testing.  So if it's not in the command line, the error must be in your implementation or your environment. FWIW, I usually use the `.Run` method and redirect the output to a temporary text file, which I then read (using the FileSystemObject) and delete. I prefer that method because I can hide the command window when running, and also there is an `async` switch so you don't have to set up a loop and check for the command being finished, as you do with `exec`. I think you can also redirect the output from `.Run` to the windows clipboard, but I've not tried that.